# a problem on random walk and maximu of its summation

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Suppose $X_n$ is random walk with $P(X_n=1)=1-P(X_n=-1)=p=1-q$. 
$M_n=\max_{1\le i\le n} S_i$, $Y_n=M_n-S_n, T_a=\min\{S_n=a\}$.
Find $P(\max_{0\le k\le T_a} Y_k <y).$

Comment: Here is some thought, if we want to particle to stay within $(0,0)$ and $(y-1,a)$, we need to make sure in each of the $a$ horizontal floors, we need to make sure the particle will not go out of $y$.
      \begin{eqnarray}
       P(\max_{0\le k\le T_a} Y_k<y)&=&\nonumber P(\max_{0\le k\le T_1} Y_k<y)P(\max_{T_1\le k\le T_2} Y_k<y)\ldots P(\max_{T_{a-1}\le k\le T_a} Y_k<y)\\
       &=&\nonumber P(\max_{0\le k\le T_1} Y_k<y)^a
      \end{eqnarray}

Comment: And on each layers, it seems to be a gambler's ruin probability. but I am not quite sure how should I do this.

Comment: In the first comment, I used $(Y_n, M_n)$ as a Markov Chain process and consider these two on the x and y axis of a graph.